# How to aggregate millions of rows using EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm trying to aggregate approximately two million rows based on user.
One user has several Transactions, each Transaction has a Platform and a TransactionType.I aggregate Platform and TransactionType columns as json and save as a single row.

But my code is slow.
How can I improve the performance?

```
  public static void AggregateTransactions()
        {
            using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
            {
                db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

                //Get a list of users who have transactions  
                var users = db.Transactions
                   .Select(x => x.User)
                   .Distinct();

                foreach (var user in users.ToList())
                {
                    //Get all transactions for a particular user
                    var _transactions = db.Transactions
                        .Include(x => x.Platform)
                        .Include(x => x.TransactionType)
                        .Where(x => x.User == user)
                        .ToList();

//Aggregate Platforms from all transactions for user
                    Dictionary<string, int> platforms = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                    foreach (var item in _transactions.Select(x => x.Platform).GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList())
                    {
                        platforms.Add(item.Key, item.Count());
                    };

//Aggregate TransactionTypes from all transactions for user
                   Dictionary<string, int> transactionTypes = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                    foreach (var item in _transactions.Select(x => x.TransactionType).GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList())
                    {
                        transactionTypes.Add(item.Key, item.Count());
                    };


                    db.Add<TransactionByDay>(new TransactionByDay
                    {
                        User = user,
                        Platforms = platforms,     //The dictionary list is represented as json in table
                        TransactionTypes = transactionTypes     //The dictionary list is represented as json in table
                    });

                    db.SaveChanges();

                }

            }

        }
```

**Update**

So a basic view of the data would look like the following:

**Tansactions Data:**

Id: b11c6b67-6c74-4bbe-f712-08d609af20cf,
UserId: 1,
PlatformId: 3,
TransactionypeId: 1

Id: 4782803f-2f6b-4d99-f717-08d609af20cf,
UserId: 1,
PlatformId: 3,
TransactionypeId: 4

**Aggregate data as TransactionPerDay:**

Id: 9df41ef2-2fc8-441b-4a2f-08d609e21559,
UserId: 1,
Platforms: {"p3":2},
TransactionsTypes: {"t1":1,"t4":1}

So in this case, two transactions are aggregated into one. You can see that the platforms and transaction types will be aggregated as json.

Comment: In your code it looks like you are doing the same thing again and again. Besides being slow, the purpose is not understandable. Can you give a subset of your data as a sample and what you are really trying to do.

Comment: Your `_transactions` query is unrelated to the `user`. Is that intentional? Doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I updated my question

Comment: @IvanStoev Sorry, that was a typo. Updated, thanks.

Comment: I've added a few comments to the code, I hope it makes my intention clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably should not be calling db.saveChanges() within the loop. Putting it outside the loop to persist the changes once, may help.

But having said this, when dealing with large volumes of data and performance is key, I've found that ADO.NET is probably a better choice. This does not mean you have to stop using Entity Framework, but perhaps for this method you could use ADO.NET. If you go down this path you could either:

1. Create a stored procedure to return the data you need to work on, populate a datatable, manipulate the data and the persist everything in bulk using sqlBulkCopy.
2. Use a stored procedure to completely perform this operation. This avoids the need to shuttle the data to your application and the entire processing can happen within the database itself.

Comment: I tried a couple ways with db.saveChanges(). I had db.saveChanges() outside the loop with if (i % 1000 == 0){db.saveChanges()} inside the loop, but didn't see much difference. I will take a closer look at the scenario you proposed, thanks.

Comment: Please keep us posted and share your findings. If I was able to help, please upvote the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Thumbs up for the base ado.net recommendation.

Comment: I'm going to go with a stored procedure. Just need to figure out how... I will ask a new question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Linq To EF is not built for speed (LinqToSQL is easier and faster IMHO, or you could run direct SQL commands with Linq EF\SQL). Anyway, I don't know how this would speed wise:

```
    using (var db = new MyContext(connectionstring))
    {

        var tbd = (from t in db.Transactions
                    group t by t.User
                    into g
                    let platforms = g.GroupBy(tt => tt.Platform.Name)
                    let trantypes = g.GroupBy(tt => tt.TransactionType.Name)
                    select new {
                       User = g.Key,
                       Platforms = platforms, 
                       TransactionTypes = trantypes 
                    }).ToList()
                    .Select(u => new TransactionByDay {
                        User=u.User, 
                        Platforms=u.Platforms.ToDictionary(tt => tt.Key, tt => tt.Count()),
                        TransactionTypes = u.TransactionTypes.ToDictionary(tt => tt.Key, tt => tt.Count())
                    });
 //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to try to do less queries and includes by getting as much data as needed first. So there is no need to include with every transaction the `Platform` and `TransactionType`, where you can just query them once in a `Dictionary` and look the data up. Further more we could do our processing in Parallel, then save all the data at once.

```
    public static void AggregateTransactions()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            //Get a list of users who have transactions  
            var transactionsByUser = db.Transactions
               .GroupBy(x => x.User) //Not sure if EF Core supports this kind of grouping
               .ToList();

            var platforms = db.Platforms.ToDictionary(ks => ks.PlatformId);
            var Transactiontypes = db.TransactionTypes.ToDictionary(ks => ks.TransactionTypeId);
            var bag = new ConccurentBag<TransactionByDay>();

            Parallel.ForEach(transactionsByUser, transaction => 
            {
                //Aggregate Platforms from all transactions for user
                Dictionary<string, int> platforms = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //This can be converted to a ConccurentDictionary

                //This can be converted to Parallel.ForEach
                foreach (var item in _transactions.Select(x => platforms[x.PlatformId]).GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList())
                {
                    platforms.Add(item.Key, item.Count());
                };

               //Aggregate TransactionTypes from all transactions for user
               Dictionary<string, int> transactionTypes = new Dictionary<string, int>(); //This can be converted to a ConccurentDictionary

                //This can be converted to Parallel.ForEach
                foreach (var item in _transactions.Select(x => Transactiontypes[c.TransactionTypeId]).GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList())
                {
                    transactionTypes.Add(item.Key, item.Count());
                };

                bag.Add(new TransactionByDay
                {
                    User = transaction.Key,
                    Platforms = platforms,     //The dictionary list is represented as json in table
                    TransactionTypes = transactionTypes     //The dictionary list is represented as json in table
                });
            });

            //Before calling this we may need to check the status of the Parallel ForEach, or just convert it back to regular foreach loop if you see no benefit.
            db.AddRange(bag);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

Variation #2

```
    public static void AggregateTransactions()
    {
        using (var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            db.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

            //Get a list of users who have transactions  
            var users = db.Transactions
               .Select(x => x.User)
               .Distinct().ToList();

            var platforms = db.Platforms.ToDictionary(ks => ks.PlatformId);
            var Transactiontypes = db.TransactionTypes.ToDictionary(ks => ks.TransactionTypeId);
            var bag = new ConccurentBag<TransactionByDay>();

            Parallel.ForEach(users, user => 
            {
                var _transactions = db.Transactions
                .Where(x => x.User == user)
                .ToList();

                //Aggregate Platforms from all transactions for user
                Dictionary<string, int> userPlatforms = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                Dictionary<string, int> userTransactions = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                foreach(var transaction in _transactions)
                {
                   if(platforms.TryGetValue(transaction.PlatformId, out var platform))
                   {
                       if(userPlatforms.TryGetValue(platform.Name, out var tmp))
                       {
                           userPlatforms[platform.Name] = tmp + 1;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           userPlatforms.Add(platform.Name, 1);
                       }
                   }

                   if(Transactiontypes.TryGetValue(transaction.TransactionTypeId, out var type))
                   {
                       if(userTransactions.TryGetValue(type.Name, out var tmp))
                       {
                           userTransactions[type.Name] = tmp + 1;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           userTransactions.Add(type.Name, 1);
                       }
                   }
                }

                bag.Add(new TransactionByDay
                {
                    User = user,
                    Platforms = userPlatforms,     //The dictionary list is represented as json in table
                    TransactionTypes = userTransactions     //The dictionary list is represented as json in table
                });

            });

            db.AddRange(bag);
            db.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Comment: I chose to split the queries per user because loading all the transactions into a single list like you have (which could  be several millions) will be a big performance hit.

Comment: I see, have you considered doing the queries in chunks instead of per user (say you hit the db for every 10K transactions)?

Comment: I have updated the answer with a second variation that gets the data per user, it may inspire you to do something similar, or even different. Have fun!

Comment: The bottleneck here may just be that you have a lot of data that you both fetch and save, you may end up just giving this entire to SQL and/or ADO and have this logic in a Stored Procedure. You may also consider having this task run nightly on a scheduler, or even doing the processing of it not per day but chunk it throughout the day, so  you have less data to work with.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to use a stored procedure. +1