# Create a stored procedure to aggregate rows

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, aggregate

Having a transaction table with the following rows:

```
Id    UserId   PlatformId    TransactionTypeId
-------------------------------------------------
 0       1          3                1
 1       1          1                2
 2       2          3                2
 3       3          2                1
 4       2          3                1
```

How do I write a stored procedure that can aggregate the rows into a new table with the following format?

```
Id    UserId   Platforms          TransactionTypeId
-------------------------------------------------
 0      1      {"p3":1,"p1":1}    {"t1":1,"t2":1}
 1      2      {"p3":2}           {"t2":1,"t1":1}
 3      3      {"p2":1}           {"t1":1}
```

So the rows are gouped by User, count each platform/transactionType and store as key/value json string.

Ref: [My previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52009050/how-to-aggregate-millions-of-rows-using-ef-core)

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: The solution will be on Azure, so I think 14.

Comment: Or is it v12 on Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `GROUP BY` and `FOR JSON`:

```
SELECT MIN(ID) AS ID, UserId, MIN(sub.x) AS Platforms, MIN(sub2.x) AS Transactions
FROM tab t
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CONCAT('p', platformId) AS platform, cnt 
            FROM (SELECT PlatformId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                  FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.UserId = t.UserId  
                  GROUP BY PlatformId) s
              FOR JSON AUTO) sub(x)
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CONCAT('t', TransactiontypeId) AS Transactions, cnt 
            FROM (SELECT TransactiontypeId, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                  FROM tab t2 WHERE t2.UserId = t.UserId  
                  GROUP BY TransactiontypeId) s
              FOR JSON AUTO) sub2(x)
GROUP BY UserId;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a9c81f1aff8fc8cdc42fcc3021081b12)**

Result is a bit different(array of key-value) but please treat it as starting point.

Comment: Is it fine to use Replace to create the json formatting I want? Replace(Replace(MIN(sub.x),'"platform":',''),'"cnt":','')

and

Replace(Replace(MIN(sub.x),'"Transactions":',''),'"cnt":','')

Comment: JSON is simply text. So you could use any string operation on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your sample JSON is not really a json, but since you want it that way:

```
SELECT u.UserId, plt.pValue, ttyp.ttValue
FROM Users AS [u]
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT '{'+STUFF( (SELECT ',"'+pn.pName+'":'+LTRIM(STR(pn.pCount))
    FROM (SELECT p.Name AS pName, COUNT(*) AS pCount 
        FROM transactions t
        left JOIN Platforms p ON p.PlatformID = t.PlatformId
        WHERE t.UserId = u.UserId
        GROUP BY p.PlatformId, p.Name
        ) pn
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')+'}'
    ) plt(pValue)
CROSS APPLY (
SELECT '{'+STUFF( (SELECT ',"'+tty.ttName+'":'+LTRIM(STR(tty.ttCount))
    FROM (SELECT tt.Name AS ttName, COUNT(*) AS ttCount 
        FROM transactions t
        left JOIN dbo.TransactionType tt ON tt.TransactionTypeId = t.TransactionTypeID
        WHERE t.UserId = u.UserId
        GROUP BY tt.TransactionTypeId, tt.Name
        ) tty
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')+'}'
    ) ttyp(ttValue)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM transactions t WHERE u.UserId = t.UserId)
ORDER BY UserId;
```

[DBFiddle Sample](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a53f486bdc12027d4c1e233ebffe09e4)

Comment: What do you mean not really json? They are json objects as far as I know? JSON objects are surrounded by curly braces {}.

JSON objects are written in key/value pairs.

Keys must be strings, and values must be a valid JSON data type (string, number, object, array, boolean or null).

Keys and values are separated by a colon.

Each key/value pair is separated by a comma.

Comment: @Leila, what I meant is that they were just son representations for a dictionary. It would be hard to serialize, deserialize them. At the end, didn't you also mark the reply returning Platform, cnt as keys rather than the one that does exactly what you asked for?